# VBA Select specific cell in PowerPoint table

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

How do you select a specific cell in a PowerPoint table ?

I need to paste into a PowerPoint table, including my Excel formatting, to a specific cell.

Code is situated in Excel!

Specifically, this is how you select a specific cell!

```
    PPSlide.Shapes("Table 4").Table.Rows(2).Cells.Item(1).Select
```

This is an informational post, I couldn't figure out how to do it for a while, so I thought I'd add.t

```
Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
Dim sht as Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Local Channels National View")

   ''''''''COPY TEMPLATE SLIDE''''''''
    ''duplicate template slide, move to end of presentation
    Set slideR = PPPres.Slides(3).Duplicate
    slideR.MoveTo (PPPres.Slides.Count)
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPPres.Slides.Count)




    sht.Range("B10:F14").Copy

    ''''select rows 2, column 1 cell
    PPSlide.Shapes("Table 4").Table.Rows(2).Cells.Item(1).Select

    '''paste
    PPApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("Paste")
```

Resources:
CellRange object - collection of cells, row or column
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/cellrange-object-powerpoint

Cell Object
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/cell-object-powerpoint

Answer (score 1):

This is how you select a specific cell:

`PPSlide.Shapes("Table 4").Table.Rows(2).Cells.Item(1).Select`

Comment: Why you answer your own question?

Comment: @DavidG. Answering your own question is completely acceptable on SO.  See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) However, I'd suggest the OP change the question to not include the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to select a single cell using its row and column properties:

```
PPSlide.Shapes("Table 4").Table.Cell(Row:=2,Column:=1).Select
```